# How to use GLKMatrixStack in Objective-C? (GLKit)

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, stack, glkit

I'm trying to port over some OpenGL code from an Android project to iOS. I've done a little bit of iOS programming before so i'm familiar with the syntax of Objective-C but I can't seem to figure out how these GLKMatrixStacks work. Here is some Java code that I am trying to port with an example of how I need to use the stack.

```
public void drawLeftHip()
{
    float[] temp = new float[16];
    System.arraycopy(mModelMatrix, 0, temp, 0, mModelMatrix.length);
    stack.push(temp);

    //Global transformations here
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, -1.0f, -.75f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, lThighAngle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  

    //draw children
    drawLeftThigh();

    //left hip
    Matrix.scaleM(mModelMatrix, 0, .25f, .25f, .25f);
    drawPackedTriangleBuffer(mSphereData, mSphereVertexCount, mModelMatrix, mColorBlack); //draw the triangle with the given model matrix

    mModelMatrix = stack.pop();
}
```

I basically make a copy of mModelMatrix (a 4x4 matrix) and push it on the stack, do my global transformations, draw children, do local transformations, and finally pop the stack.

I've tried using a NSMutableArray for the purpose of a stack but I can't use it because I need to use GLKMatrix4 which is not if type (id).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GLKMatrix4`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLKit/Reference/GLKMatrix4/Reference/reference.html) represents a 4x4 matrix. It's just a union encapsulating a 16-element `float` array, so it's analogous to the `float[16]` array in your example. If you work with `GLKBaseEffect` you're already using these for your ModelView and Projection matrices. (If you're rolling your own shaders, using the [GLKit matrix/vector types and corresponding math utilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLKit/Reference/GLKit_Collection/_index.html) is a good idea anyway, since they're optimized to provide good performance on iOS devices.)

To follow the pattern of your example:

1. Use `GLKMatrixStackCreate` to create a stack, then `GLKMatrixStackLoad` to copy your current ModelView matrix onto the stack. This function automatically copies the matrix so you don't need to create a copy yourself as in your example.
2. Use [`GLKMatrix4Translate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLKit/Reference/GLKMatrix4/Reference/reference.html), [`GLKMatrix4Rotate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLKit/Reference/GLKMatrix4/Reference/reference.html), etc to transform your ModelView matrix before drawing with it. (Don't forget to upload the changed matrices to your shader's uniform variables, or if using `GLKBaseEffect` update its `transform` property and tell it to `prepareToDraw`, before drawing.)
3. Finally, use one of the `GLKMatrixStackGet` functions to retrieve the saved matrix from the stack.

This pattern doesn't actually make use of the stack, though -- it just saves and loads a single matrix. You can extend the pattern by using `GLMatrixStackPush` to save additional matrices and `GLKMatrixStackPop` to restore to a prior state. (The pop function doesn't return the top matrix before disposing of it, so use a `GLKMatrixStackGet` function if you want to retrieve it first.) This pattern still doesn't make optimal use of the stack, though -- a better way is to keep all your matrix operations in the stack. Here's a quick (untested) example:

```
// subclass of GLKViewController as in the "OpenGL Game" Xcode template
@implementation MyViewController
{
    GLKMatrixStack mvStack;
}

- (void)setupGL
{
    // ... other setup code ...

    // set up base transform
    mvStack = GLKMatrixStackCreate(NULL);
    GLKMatrixStackTranslate(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);
    GLKMatrixStackScale(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);
    GLKMatrixStackRotate(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);
}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // save the base transform
    GLKMatrixStackPush(mvStack);

    // additional transforms for figure
    GLKMatrixStackTranslate(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);
    GLKMatrixStackScale(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);
    GLKMatrixStackRotate(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);

    [self drawBody];

    // restore the base transform
    GLKMatrixStackPop(mvStack);
}

- (void)drawBody
{
    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrixStackGetMatrix4(mvStack);
    // ... draw body ...

    // save body transform 
    GLKMatrixStackPush(mvStack);

    // transform to left leg coordinate space
    GLKMatrixStackTranslate(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);
    GLKMatrixStackScale(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);
    GLKMatrixStackRotate(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);

    [self drawLeg];

    // restore to body coordinates
    GLKMatrixStackPop(mvStack);

    // transform to right leg coordinate space
    GLKMatrixStackTranslate(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);
    GLKMatrixStackScale(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);
    GLKMatrixStackRotate(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);

    [self drawLeg];

    // restore to body coordinates
    GLKMatrixStackPop(mvStack);
}

- (void)drawLeg
{
    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrixStackGetMatrix4(mvStack);
    // ... draw upper leg ...

    // save upper leg transform 
    GLKMatrixStackPush(mvStack);

    // transform to lower leg coordinate space
    GLKMatrixStackTranslate(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);
    GLKMatrixStackScale(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);
    GLKMatrixStackRotate(mvStack, /* ... coords ... */);

    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrixStackGetMatrix4(mvStack);
    // ... draw lower leg ...

    // restore to upper leg coordinates
    GLKMatrixStackPop(mvStack);
}
```

Read the documentation on [`GLKMatrixStack`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLKit/Reference/GLKMatrixStack/Reference/reference.html) for more info.